# Complex validation scenarios

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have some complex validation scenarios that I need some help with.

I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class FooModel {
    public class BarModel {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public DateTime? BirthDate {get;set;}
    }

    public List<BarModel> Bars {get;set;}

    // 10 BarModels added in controller
    public FooModel() { Bars = new List<BarModel>(); }

    public bool Choose1 {get;set;}
    public bool Choose2 {get;set;}
}
```

Now, depending on the value of Choose1, I need to either valudate that all BarModel's have data set (Required validation) if Choose1 is true, or if Choose1 is false then the first two items in the list will be ignored.

Second, if Choose2 is true, then I only want to collect birthdate for each item in Bars, and ignore the Name property.

I've looked at a custom attribute, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to apply it to the nested class and get at the values in the parent class.  I've also not found a way that I can easily only validate some items in a collection.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I've also considered IValidatableObject, but I am interested in a solution that will also work client side, if possible.  Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own validation with implementing [IValidatableObject](http://en.hugon.ws/articles/mvc-3/the-ivalidatableobject-interface/)

```
public class FooModel : IValidatableObject {

public class BarModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime? BirthDate {get;set;}
}

public List<BarModel> Bars {get;set;}

// 10 BarModels added in controller
public FooModel() { Bars = new List<BarModel>(); }

public bool Choose1 {get;set;}
public bool Choose2 {get;set;}

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (Choose1)
    {
        // do your validation and return result if needed:
        yield return new ValidationResult("The title is mandatory.");
    }
    // ...
}

}
```

Comment: I had considered this, however it doesn't support Client Side validation that I am aware of.

Comment: You didn't write that you need Client Side validation but I think it's not possible in your situation, your need the filled ViewModel on server side to archive this. You could consider sending your data by ajax and return the validation result to the client.